# PHP: cookie exists, but function doesn't find it using isset

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, isset

Using CodeIgniter I'm checking if a cookie exists by using the isset() function and depending on that I redirect to an other controller. Now my problem is that I get a redirect-loop because the check_logged_in function thinks that the cookie doesn't exists.

Here is my code:

This function resides in the `login_helper`.

```
function check_logged_in()  
{  
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['uid']))  
    {   
        redirect('users/login');  
        return FALSE;   
    }
    else
    { 
         return TRUE;
}
```

this next function resides in the `home` controller and calls the check_logged_in() function, described above.

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('login');
    $logged_in = check_logged_in();

    if($logged_in === TRUE)
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('pages/home_view');
        $this->load->view('pages/advanced_search_view');
        $this->load->view('pages/contact_information_view');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
}
```

the next function resides in the `users` controller

```
public function login()
{
    if(isset($_COOKIE['uid']))
    { 
        redirect(home); 
    }
    else
    {
        -some unrelated code-
    }
```

when the cookie does exist and I run either the `home/index` function or the `users/login` function I end up in a redirect loop. When the cookie doesn't exist I end up at my login page, so it seems the `users/login` cookie check works correctly but the `home/index` function does not.

---

I have tried putting

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['uid']))  
{   
    redirect('users/login');     
}
```

directly in the `home/index` function but it gave the same problems.

Comment: Have you tried to echo $_COOKIE['uid']? Is it NULL? Seems like that would be a good place to start perhaps.

Comment: How do you set the cookie? Cookie's domain, path?

Comment: I get the value of the cookie when I echo it, in my case it's '1234'.

Comment: I set the cookie through `setcookie('uid',$uid);`

Comment: codeigniter already have cookie helper functions ,set_cookie() and get_cookie, why don't you use thess function rather. I am not sure but possible codeigniter clears the global arrays before calling your controller

Comment: make sure you are using the correct domain. www.example.com or example.com differs on result. One more thing? Why not use the `Session` class?

Comment: Solved! It turned out that the path of the cookie was set to 'index.php/users' and not to '/' (root). Thank you all.

Comment: @Dasyel You might want to answer your question just for the Q&A format of this site. That way other people that have the same problem can find the answer more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Put the login check in the Constructor. Give it a generic name - and have it do something useful like return info from the cookie, and/or from a database lookup.

```
function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
 // load the model
 $this->load->model( 'login_model' );

 // if logged in, return $this->user
 if(! $this->user = $this->login_model->verifyUser() ) 
 { redirect('users/login', 'refresh'); }

 } // construct
```

And now $this->user is available for your methods, all the way to the view.

If you need an "admin" that can do more then a user, in the same way

```
 $this->admin = $this->login_model->verifyAdmin() ;
```

Then you can change what happens in verifyAdmin(), and your class does not have to get updated.